# google pay error OR_BIBED_07 when resolving "ResolvableApiException: 6: BuyFlow UI needs to be shown"

Tags: android, google-pay

I'm currently having an issue with google pay on production. With test cards everything is working fine but as soon it comes to production with 3ds i have the following issue.

When the google pay flow starts I get first ("Of course") the error "**ResolvableApiException: 6: BuyFlow UI needs to be shown**". No problem so far because then intent starts and it will try to show the ui. But as soon as it slides up now now the error "**Request failed: An unexpected error has occured. Please try again later. OR_BIBED_07**". I'm not using stripe or anything. The merchant comes from the backend and works with the web app already. I have by now really no clue why this happens. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: In my case, I used some API keys for the test environment and some for the production, so make sure you have all the right API keys (Google and possibly your payment provider)

Comment: Find any solutions regarding this?